# Unable to open Visualforce page from LWC on Salesforce1, it redirects to web page and asks for password. Works well in IOS issue in Android

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, navigation

I am trying to open a Visualforce Page in Mobile device on a button click from LWC. I am using function

```
 navigateToVFPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: '/apex/LP_AccountFleetTableLevels?accountId='+ this.recordId
            }
        }).then(generatedUrl => {
            window.open(generatedUrl);

        });
    }
```

And Calling this on button click.

It is working well on iOS but redirecting to web in Android.

Let me know if there is any workaround for the same I have tried using `sforce.one.navigatetoURL` but that is not working in LWC.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for me was to replace

```
window.open(generatedUrl);
```

with

```
window.location.replace(generatedUrl);
```

In addition I used formFactor to apply logic in case desktop needed different behaviour to mobile.

```
import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';
```